# how to add dashed horizontal line with label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted a line plot. I have added a horizontal line on the plot. How to take horizontal line red dashed?

```
# Sample Data 

library(tidyverse)
Month= c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun")
a = c(11,10,9,8,4,8)

test= data_frame(Month,a) 
test$cum_total <- cumsum(test$a)

test$Month <- factor(test$Month, month.abb)

# ggplot

ggplot(data=test, aes(x=Month, y=cum_total, group=1)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  geom_hline(yintercept=40)+
  annotate("text", x = "Feb", y = 40, label = "Previous Level", vjust = -0.5)
```

Comment: Replace your `geom_hline()` with `geom_hline(yintercept = 40, linetype = 2, colour = "red")` and it should be dashed and red.

Answer (score 27):

to make the horizontal line dashed and red the following arguments should be included in the geom_hline function call:

`linetype = 'dotted', col = 'red'`

```
# Sample Data 

library(tidyverse)
Month= c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun")
a = c(11,10,9,8,4,8)

test= data_frame(Month,a) 
test$cum_total <- cumsum(test$a)

test$Month <- factor(test$Month, month.abb)

# ggplot

ggplot(data=test, aes(x=Month, y=cum_total, group=1)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  geom_hline(yintercept=40, linetype='dotted', col = 'red')+
  annotate("text", x = "Feb", y = 40, label = "Previous Level", vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Why should he do that?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I still don't see any explanation as to why he should do that

Comment: I would change it to `linetype = 'dashed'`.